# C - How to iterate through an ADT struct?

Tags: c, struct, abstract-data-type

I am making a set ADT for a school assignment, and I'm pretty close to completion. However I am having some difficulties as to how I should iterate over the various items in a struct: 
It is essential that the "element" member of the set structure is a void pointer, if it was of the type int, I could `set->element[i]`. Any suggestions to alternatives?

```
struct set
{
    void *element;
    int size;
    cmpfunc_t cmpfunc;
    set_t *start;
    set_t *next;
};

int set_contains(set_t *set, void *elem)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<set->size;++i)
      if(set->element[i] == elem)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `void **element;`? You can't dereference like that, otherwise ...

Comment: "element" is of type pointer to void in what you show and could not be of type void.

Comment: Sorry, void pointer was what  I meant. Edit fixed.

Comment: What do you mean, "I could `set->element[i]`" where `set->element` is `int`?! You most certainly could *not*! You can't dereference an `int`, and you can't dereference a `void *` (which I note has been explained), either... While we're on the topic of types and "size types" there's one you should certainly consider in place of `int` here: `size_t` is the type that `strlen` returns, that `malloc` takes as an argument and probably what you should use as your type for `set->size` and `i`. It's just an idiom, but there could also be some signed integer processing overhead in `i<set->size`...

Comment: What's the use you meant for `*start` and `*next`? How is defined `cmpfunc_t`? Is the struct set meant for a single element, for a set of element of the same kind or for a lot of element of different kind?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement a linked list of structures, and want to iterate across the list checking to see if a pointer matches, however the element pointer can be a pointer to an array, the number of entries of which are in size?  Or is size the size of the element pointed to which is not an array?

Comment: ADTs like these with void pointers is very "old school" - in both positive and negative ways. Positive since you are actually getting taught to write ADTs which is good practice in C. Negative since generic programming with void pointers is unsafe and generally messy. The modern way to write similar code would be to either use `_Generic` or to use callback functions that contain the type-specific behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ADT structure doesn't really make a lot of sense; it looks like you've tried to cross-breed different design patterns, those being the use of an array to hold the set elements, and the use of a linked-list to hold the set.

I'll take the liberty of modifying the structure so that it is a little more in line with either pattern. First of all, `typedef`'s hide information -> avoid them whenever possible.

**First pattern: Use an array of elements**

```
struct set {
  void **elements;              /* array of elements    */
  int nElem;                    /* array count          */
  size_t elemSize;              /* size of element type */
  int(*cmpFunc)(void*, void*);  /* equality comparison  */
};
```

The `elemSize` field is used to allocate and copy new elements without knowing their datatype. This is common to both patterns, and to generic ADT's in general. To iterate over this set, use:

```
int set_contains(struct set *pSet, void *elem) {
  for (int i = 0; i < pSet->nElem; ++i) {
    if (pSet->cmpFunc(pSet->elements[i], elem))
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Second pattern: Use a linked-list to represent the set**

```
struct node {
  void *data;         /* element data      */
  struct node *next;  /* next node in list */
};

struct set{
  struct node *head;            /* first element       */
  size_t elemSize;              /* size of data type   */
  int(*cmpFunc)(void*, void*);  /* equality comparison */
};
```

The element size and comparison function are attributes of a given set, not the data that is contained in that set, so they are defined on the `set` structure, not the `node` structure, which only defines the data and the associated link. To iterate over this set, use:

```
int set_contains(struct set *pSet, void *elem) {
  struct node *head = pSet->head;
  while(head) {
    if (pSet->cmpFunc(head->data, elem))
      return 1;
    head = head->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```